# Show that the set is a partition of $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

Let $A\neq \emptyset\neq B$ be sets, $C\subseteq A$, $D\subseteq B$ subsets and $f:A\rightarrow B$ a map.

I want to show that the set $\{f^{-1}(\{x\})\mid x\in\text{im} f\}$ is a partition of $A$.

$$$$

For that do we have to show that the union of all such sets is equal to $A$ and the intersection of them is the empty set?

Could you give me a hint how we could do that?

Comment: $f$ is a function, so the $f^{-1}\{x\}$ must be disjoint.

Comment: Except the union and the intersection, do we have to show also that the empty set is not included? @Dzoooks

Comment: @MaryStar Please mark (nice) answers as accepted $\left( \color{limegreen}{\checkmark}\right)$. It would show that you appreciate effort  and the contribution of the answerer. Please check all your other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "the union of all such sets is equal to A" you need to use the definition of the Domain of a function f. Try starting with $ a \in A$ and find a set of the form $ f^{-1}(\{x\}) $ that contains a.

For "the intersection of them is the empty set", assume that for $ x_1 \ne x_2 $ you have $ a \in f^{-1}(\{x_1\})$ and $ a \in f^{-1}(\{x_2\})$. Is this consistent with f being a function?

As a side note, although it is not wrong, you are using x to refer to the images of f. I think $ f^{-1}(\{y\}) $ would be clearer.

Comment: The domain of a function is the set of its possible inputs, i.e., the set of input values where for which the function is defined. This means it is the set of all values $a\in A$ such that there is a $y$ with $f(a)=y$. That means that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ contains $a$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what I had in mind. Basically $a \in f^{-1}(\{f(a)\})$

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-)